# Whalewatching around New York City

Tags: usa, new-york-city, nature-and-wildlife, outdoor-activities, whalewatching

Where can I go for whalewatching in/around(travel time ~1 h) New York City? I will be there in mid of July and i heared, that the whalewatching season starts at the beginning of July.

Comment: you say in/around - how far is "around"? Is Boston acceptable, for example (4 hours by bus)?

Comment: You want to do it in the wild?  Or within 1 hour of New York City?

Comment: @Coxer: my bad, I should have said Wal-mart ;-) (per [definition of whale](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=whale&defid=814486))

Comment: @vartec Those are not the only definitions of "whale" in New York City.

Comment: Whale watching in Boston is the best, in my experience, but, I also agree to what Jim Gaffigan once said, I went whale watching - an activity I wouldn't even do sitting at home :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest expanding your range since 1 hour out of New York city won't get you very far along the coast.  There are several places that say they offer but you might have to call them to see what they will actually offer.

- [Rockaway Ferry](http://www.rockawayferry.com/dolphin_whale_watching.htm)
- [Several listed in Freeport](http://www.discoverlongisland.com/visitors/ThingsResult.aspx/minor/WEBSEALWT)

Of course there is other kind of [Whale Watching available](http://ny.eater.com/archives/2013/01/a_guide_to_whale_watching_in_new_york_city.php) as far as New York is concerned. :)